# How to add border-bottom on active link

Tags: javascript, css

How can I add border-bottom on btn_articles and btn_posts when I click one of them? I tried to add/remove the active class but it didn't work. Any help or idea is appreciated.

```js
let btn_articles = document.getElementById('btn_articles');
btn_articles.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let articles = document.getElementById('container_articles');
    let container_posts = document.getElementById('container_posts');
    articles.style.display = "flex";
    container_posts.style.display = "none";
})


let btn_posts = document.getElementById('btn_posts');
btn_posts.addEventListener('click',function(){
    let container_posts = document.getElementById('container_posts');
    let articles = document.getElementById('container_articles');
    container_posts.style.display = "flex";
    articles.style.display = "none";

})
```

```css
.btn-profile-buttons:hover{
    color:#4dcadd;
    border-bottom:3px solid #4dzadd;
}
.btn-profile-buttons{
    border-bottom:3px solid #4dzadd;
}
.profile-buttons a{
    margin:0rem 2rem;
    padding:0.5rem 1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.active{
  color:#4dzadd;
  border-bottom:3px solid #4dzadd;
}
```

```html
        <div class="profile-buttons" id = "profile-buttons">
            <a id = "btn_articles" href = "#" class = "btn-profile-buttons active">Articles </a>
            <a id = "btn_posts" href = "#" class = "btn-profile-buttons ">Posts </a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is no page redirection, you can try this.

```js
$('#profile-buttons a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#profile-buttons a").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.btn-profile-buttons:hover {
  color: #4dcadd;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #4dzadd;
}

.btn-profile-buttons {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #4dzadd;
}

.profile-buttons a {
  margin: 0rem 2rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.active {
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profile-buttons" id="profile-buttons">
  <a id="btn_articles" href="#" class="btn-profile-buttons active">Articles </a>
  <a id="btn_posts" href="#" class="btn-profile-buttons ">Posts </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of Psudo Classed (Before and After):

```css
/*Remove Default styles of <a> tag and add padding*/

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    display: inline-block; /* this element for browser compatibility*/
    position: relative;
}

a:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: ©;
    Left: 0;
  }


/*an hover add border-bottom */
  a:hover:after {
      display: block;
      border-bottom-color: blue;
  }
/*an active means when the click on link it'll appear ) add border-bottom*/

  a:active:after {
      display: block;
      border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

Comment: The pseudo element `:active` is only works during the clicking of an element.